# concatenating two datasets and getting unexpected results in SAS

Tags: io, sas, set, concatenation

I came across a rather weird situation where I concatenated two datasets and got really unexpected results. Here's the setup:

```
data a;
    do i=1 to 100;
        output;
    end;
run;


data b;
    do j=5 to 79;
        output;
    end;
run;

data c;
    set a b;
    if j=. then j=i;
run;
```

Can someone explain to me why the j takes on the value of "1" for the first 100 observations? It looks like j is being retained, but even weirder, if I change the conditional to:

```
data c;
    set a b;
    if i=. then i=j;
run;
```

Then a "retain" statement" would imply that after the 100th observation, you should see 100 retained down, but it isn't! It's 5! What is going on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

All variables that are sourced from input datasets are "retained".  You just don't normally notice it because the values are overwritten when the SET statement executes. In your example dataset `B` does not contribute to the first few observations so the value you put into the variable `J` on the first iteration of the data step is not overwritten until you start reading from dataset `B`.

The other wrinkle is that when you do make the transition from reading dataset `A` to reading dateset `B` then the variables that are sourced from `A` are cleared.

Adding some PUT statements to your data step so you can watch what is happening will make it clearer.

```
data both;
  put / 'TOP   :' (_n_ i j) (=);
  set a(obs=3) b(obs=3) ;
  put 'MIDDLE:' (_n_ i j) (=);
  if missing(j) then j=i ;
  put 'BOTTOM:' (_n_ i j) (=);
run;
```

Results

```
TOP   :_N_=1 i=. j=.
MIDDLE:_N_=1 i=1 j=.
BOTTOM:_N_=1 i=1 j=1

TOP   :_N_=2 i=1 j=1
MIDDLE:_N_=2 i=2 j=1
BOTTOM:_N_=2 i=2 j=1

TOP   :_N_=3 i=2 j=1
MIDDLE:_N_=3 i=3 j=1
BOTTOM:_N_=3 i=3 j=1

TOP   :_N_=4 i=3 j=1
MIDDLE:_N_=4 i=. j=5
BOTTOM:_N_=4 i=. j=5

TOP   :_N_=5 i=. j=5
MIDDLE:_N_=5 i=. j=6
BOTTOM:_N_=5 i=. j=6

TOP   :_N_=6 i=. j=6
MIDDLE:_N_=6 i=. j=7
BOTTOM:_N_=6 i=. j=7

TOP   :_N_=7 i=. j=7
```

Comment: I understand doing this for a merge statement, but what's the purpose of having it this way for the set statement?

Comment: I suspect that it is just the way that it worked out.  And once you have a system that works a particular way you can't change it without breaking existing programs.